# output is showing null

Tags: mysql, sql, null, output

![enter image description here][1]I get the output is NULL for  the below program:

```
create procedure sr8(out q int,out l int)
begin
declare m int;
declare q int;
declare q1 int;


select count(a) into p1 from sr where a='agree';

set q1=q1+p1;    

set q1=q1*3;

set q=q1+q2+q3+q4;
select count(*) into m from testserve;

set q=q*100;
set m=m*40;
set q=q/m;
```

output:

q1=0+5;
15=5*3
q=15
m=121 rows
q=150
m=121*40
q=150/(121*40);
here the output of q is showing NULL

HOw to get the output of q?????

Comment: please come to gmail mygmail is dmahesh333@gmail.com so  i can show you completely please help me thanks in advance

Comment: Bro I really trying to provide screenshots but i am unable to do

Comment: please come to gmail i provide my screenshots and  show you what is my problem in my system

Comment: php for frontend <br>mysql for backend<br>IIS7 Server<br> and this above code is mysql procedure

Answer (score 0):

q1 is not initialized.

When you write

```
set q1=q1+p1;
```

you assume its initial value is 0, but it must be null.

=> just initialize it by replacing this line by

```
set q1=p1;
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with mysql but I'd also guess that have a parameter called `q` and a local variable called `q` may introduce some issues here also.